# Deployment of LocalState folder

Tags: windows-8

I'm using the LocalState folder to enable caching for my Windows 8 application. To provide sample data (the application uses a webservice to gather it's data), I would like to provide a default bunch of data already cached.

Can I provide sample data for LocalState that will be in the application package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample JS code - should be able to convert to .NET fairly easily - use async/await in place of the Promises.

```
WinJS.Application.local.exists('somedata.json').done(
               function (found) {
                   if (!found) {
                       return copyStartData('somedata.json');
                   }
               }
           );

function copyStartData(copyfile) {
        return Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFolderAsync('startdata').then(
            function (startData) {
                return startData.getFileAsync(copyfile).then(
                    function (file) {
                        if (file) {
                            return file.copyAsync(WinJS.Application.local.folder);
                        }
                    });
            });
    }
```

The function takes the name of a file you want to copy from your install package to the users local machine.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the file(s) into your package and then on startup check to see if there is already data in the Local Folder, if not, copy/populate it from the package storage (see [CopyAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227104.aspx), for instance).  If so, do nothing.